# docker: accessing linux-container service from windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-network

I need to access a service in a Linux docker container from a Windows docker container.

**Setup:**

- Host: Windows 10 installed "Docker for Windows"
- Linux Container: publish port 8080
- Windows Container: access port 8080 of Linux container

Creating a shared network does not work: [docker share network with windows and linux containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446467/docker-share-network-with-windows-and-linux-containers)

Mixing Windows and Linux containers with docker-compose does not work, since `platform` is not supported anymore in docker-compose file: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5872

Am I missing something or is it not possible to access Linux container services from a windows container?