# Reference Windows containers by name from Linux containers in Docker Desktop

Tags: linux, windows, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have 2 Windows containers and 2 Linux containers that I am trying to make work together on Docker Desktop. I have separate compose files for both, and when I "compose up" both (using the "Switch to Windows/Linux containers..." in between), they *can* communicate using the internal IP addresses they got.
However, when I try to use the service names of the compose files, they can't find each other.

I have tried anything I could think of with respect to the `networking:` part of compose files, to try and get them in the same network :

- use the same network name in both compose files
- use the same network name in both, but declare one `external`
- custom names, with and without using `default` and `external`

(basically, I tried everything mentioned [in this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088279/communication-between-multiple-docker-compose-projects))

As also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446467/docker-share-network-with-windows-and-linux-containers), there seems to be no way for the Windows context to see the Linux context. If one side has the network `external`, you get an error that the network is unknown. If both define the same network name (not using `external`), then they still don't see each other.

The two sample compose files below illustrate the issue. `linuxservice` and `nodered` can't reference `winservice`, but can reach that container on it's internal IP address. Trying localhost:9340 from `nodered` also didn't work, and resulted in a 'connection refused' error.

Compose file for my Linux containers:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    linuxservice:
        image: myregistry/mycontainer:development
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
    nodered:
        image: nodered/node-red
        ports: 
            - 1880:1880
        volumes:
            - 'C:/data/Docker/nr-volume:/data'

networks:
    default:
        name: docker-net
```

Compose file for my Windows containers:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  windb:
    image: myregistry/olmysql:v2
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  winservice:
    image: myregistry/connect:latest
    ports:
      - 9340:9340
    depends_on:
      - windb
  
networks: 
  default:
    name: docker-net
```

Is there any way these can containers can be made to communicate by name instead of by IP address?
Assuming there is no way to get them in one network, would it be possible to create some kind of DNS in either network that works across the two networks? Or is there a way to allow them to use `localhost:9340`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course I find something that at least works as soon as I have posted the question.

Using `host.docker.internal:9340` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540) at least gets rid of having to use IP addresses.

I'll leave this question open for now, just in case someone knows a way to make the Linux and Windows networks see each other's services.